# Minimum enum size not working in Delphi

Tags: delphi, enums

In order to interact with C/C++ structs I have to set minimum enum size in Delphi record to 4. However, I cannot get it to work properly.

```
type
  TFooEnum = (e1, e2, e3);

  {$Z4}
  TFoo = record
  public
    f: TFooEnum;
    b: byte;
  end;
  {$Z1}

  writeln(SizeOf(TFoo)); -> output is 2 instead of 8
```

I have also tried with `{$Z+}` and `{$MINENUMSIZE 4}` It only works if I set it in compiler options for whole project, but that messes up other records memory layouts where enums have to be 1 byte in size.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The size is a property of the enumerated type itself. So you must declare your enumerated type like so:

```
type
  {$Z4}
  TFooEnum = (e1, e2, e3);
  {$Z1}
```

The way to think about this is that record layout, for aligned records, is determined entirely by size and alignment properties of the record's members. The `$MINENUMSIZE` directive only inflences layour indirectly, by way of its impact on the size and alignment properties of any enumerated type members.

Comment: Just three more lines in documentation and I wouldn't have to ask stupid questions. Thanks!

Comment: I guess this is one of those things that is perhaps hard to anticipate as a documentation writer. If you already have the right mental model for record layout, then it might not occur to you that somebody could think that `$MINENUMSIZE` would directly influence record layout. The docs do say, *if the type was declared in the {$Z1} state (the default). If an enumerated type has more than 256 values, or if the type was declared in the {$Z2} state, it is stored as an unsigned word. Finally, ....* The key here is the phrase **declared in the {$ZX} state**.

Comment: I use packed records when I need exact layout. But I could not get it to work with or without packed, so I left packed out from the question.

Comment: I was reading the docs, but the words had completely different meaning in my head :)

Comment: Packing records is usually the wrong way to achieve a particular layout. What you'll end up doing is giving your record an alignment of 1 and so mis-aligning all members with alignment > 1. If only the packed keyword did not exist, people would not be tempted to (mis)use it as much as they do. I speak from the bitter experience of somebody who has to maintain a library full of packed records that need to remain packed for binary compatibility. I made the original mistake when I knew less than I do now.

Comment: I see from where you are coming from, but in some cases packed record is way to go. I am not talking about structures where I made wrong decision of using packed in the first place and record could be aligned either way. I am talking about interactions with OS and binary formats where you can have byte - word - byte members that have to occupy double word space. If you don't use packed you cannot achieve such layout.

Comment: That's one way to do it, but you still end up with mis-alignment. In that scenario I prefer to do the interop in a bespoke way but keep the data in memory in a properly aligned structure.